# Wordpress enqueue function is not being called from functions.php; stylesheet not added

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am building my first wordpress theme and am trying to enqueue an external style.css file.

The file is located in the theme's main directory.

I have created a functions.php file and have added the following code into:

```
<?php

function addExternalStuff(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

}  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','addExternalStuff');
```

This is exactly what tutorials and documentation says to add.

I've also used wp_enqueue_style in add_action().

```
<?php

function addExternalStuff(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

}  
add_action('wp_enqueue_style','addExternalStuff');
```

Nothing happens. The stylesheet is not added to the code. I've added an echo as well at the top of the function, and it is not printed. I have also added an echo at the very top of functions.php, outside the addExternalStuff() function and it prints, meaning this is the correction functions.php file.

Comment: did you ever call `addExternalStuff`  my guess is "no"

Comment: No, I assumed that's what add_action did, as none of the tutorials I used actually called the function. Plus if I look at one of WP's default theme's functions.php file, there is no call, only the definition and add_action. Am I missing something? Are these functions supposed to be called from another file? Placing a call at end of functions.php still did not add the stylesheet.

Comment: Are you trying to enqueue the parent style.css file into your child theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, I learned that I did not include [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/#user-contributed-notes) in the header of my header.php file. This is how Wordpress adds the stylesheet to the header and enqueue can't without it (also `wp_footer` in footer.php).

In header.php:

```
<head>

     <?php wp_head() ?>

</head>
```

In functions.php also used `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_stylesheet_uri()` so that I could call a stylesheet with a unique name other than the default style.css.

```
  <?php

    function addExternalStuff(){
        wp_enqueue_style('style',get_template_directory_uri().'css/new_stylesheet.css');

    }  
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','addExternalStuff');
```

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to post an answer to your own question, good job!

Comment: this 6 month old comment just saved my whole night...I've been checking my syntax for 2 hours, apparently I've missed the wp_head thing too. Thanks!